# Does this optimization problem have a unique solution?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I have come across a seemingly simple optimization problem. Let $h\in L^1(0,1)$; consider the optimization problem 
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\min \int_0^1\int_0^t h(s)dsdt\\
\text{s.t. } \int_0^1h(t)(1-t)>1/2, \quad 0\le h(t)\le 2.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
There seems to be infinitely many local minimizers to this problem. The first-order optimality condition is derived as
\begin{equation}
\int_t^11\,ds-\mu_1(1-t)+\mu_2(t)-\mu_3(t)=0,
\end{equation} 
where $\mu_1$, $\mu_2(t)$, and $\mu_3(t)$ are non-negative Lagrange multipliers. The only legitimate value for these multipliers will be $\mu_1=1$, $\mu_2(t)=\mu_3(1)=0$; but, this basically means no information except that $\int_0^1h_{opt}(t)(1-t)=1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Your objective coincides with the left-hand side of your integral constraint. Hence, your problem does not possess any minimizer, since the infimal value is $1/2$ but it cannot be achieved.